# $H\leq K \leq G$ and $K \trianglelefteq G \Rightarrow$ $K/H \trianglelefteq G/H$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be group and $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.

**Statement**

If $H\leq K \leq G$ and $K \trianglelefteq G$, then $K/H \trianglelefteq G/H$ holds.

I hear that this is proven by the second isomorphism theorem, but I don't know why.

The statement of the second isomorphism theorem is here.

**Let $G$ be a group, $S\leq G$ and $N\trianglelefteq G.$**

**Then, $SN\leq G, S\cap N\trianglelefteq S$ and $(SN/N) \cong S/(S\cap N)$ hold.**

In order to prove $K/H \trianglelefteq G/H$, how should I the second isomorphism theorem ?

Comment: You may want to check how the person who told you to use the "second isomorphism theorem" numbers their isomorphism theorems. The numbering is not universal.  I would suggest mapping $G/H$ to $G/K$ by $gH\longmapsto gK$, verifying this is a homomorphism, and figuring out its kernel.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The mapping is homomorphic and it's kernel is $K/H$, so $K/H \trianglelefteq G/H$ from the isomorphism theorem . Is this O.K. ?

Comment: Yes, but if I were grading I would want a justification that the map is a homomorphism; for one thing, one needs to verify it is well defined. But that's the idea. In fact, this is how one proves the isomorphism theorem that says that $(G/H)/(K/H)\cong G/K$. Which, by the way, *I* call the Second Isomorphism Theorem....

Comment: Can you give an answer without using group homomorphisms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be proven in another way. First, show that indeed $K/H$ is a subgroup of $G/H$. For normality, take $kH\in K/H$ and $gH\in G/H$, and note that $g^{-1}HkHgH=g^{-1}kgH$. Since $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, we have $g^{-1}kg\in K$, so $g^{-1}HkHgH\in K/H$, and hence $K/H$ is a normal subgroup of $G/H$.